# How to pass data to another NSViewController before viewdidload of that controller is called

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

Whenever I load another window with its view controller, I am trying to pass some data to it. That data need to be used during viewdidload is called but by the time viewdidload is called value is not assigned. I need a way where we can pass data between view controllers of two different windows before viewdidload of second controller is called.
My Sample code:

```
{

            let storyboardName = NSStoryboard.Name(stringLiteral: "Main")
            let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)

            let storyboardID = NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(stringLiteral: "MainWindowController")

            if let chooseWindowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: storyboardID) as? NSWindowController {
                if let chooseVC = chooseWindowController.contentViewController as? ViewController {

                chooseVC.buttonAction = "NewDocument"
                }

                chooseWindowController.showWindow(nil)
            }
```

Comment: One way is to pass data to the `destination` view controller when you instantiate it from the `source` view controller assuming you are using MVC pattern.

Comment: No we can't pass data while instantiating window controller as per my knowledge, if you have tried it please share.

Comment: Can't you use the data in `didSet` of `buttonAction` instead of `viewDidLoad`?